# Redis sorted set and solving ties

Tags: lua, redis, sortedset

I'm using a Redis sorted set to store a ranking for a project I'm working on.  We hadn't anticipated (!) how we wanted to handle ties. Redis sorts lexicographically the entries that have the same score, but what we want to do is instead give the same rank to all the entries that have the same score, so for instance in the case of

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANGE foo 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "first"
2) "3"
3) "second3"
4) "2"
5) "second2"
6) "2"
7) "second1"
8) "2"
9) "fifth"
10) "1"
```

we want to consider `second1`, `second2` and `second3` as both having position 2, and `fifth` to have position 5.  Hence there is no entry in the third or fourth position.  `ZREVRANK` is not useful here, so what's the best way to get the number I'm looking for?

Comment: 0

I am facing the same issue, My code is this: DenseRank.java -- https://gist.github.com/Ravikumarmaddi/15071e898e03634c70f02472952a76af

I felt some problem in LUE script. But I am not good in Lue script.

I need your help.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me one way is writing a little Lua script and use the `EVAL` command.  The resulting operation has still logarithmic complexity.

For example, suppose we are interested in the position of `second2`.  In the script, first we get its score with `ZSCORE`, obtaining 2.  Then we get the first entry with that score using `ZRANGEBYSCORE`, obtaining `second3`.  The position we're after is then `ZREVRANK` of `second3` plus 1.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZSCORE foo second2
"2"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANGEBYSCORE foo 2 2 LIMIT 0 1
1) "second3"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANK foo second3
(integer) 1
```

So the script could be something like

```
local score = redis.call('zscore', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
if score then
  local member = redis.call('zrevrangebyscore', KEYS[1], score, score, 'limit', 0, 1)
  return redis.call('zrevrank', KEYS[1], member[1]) + 1
else return -1 end
```

Comment: @emostar Thanks for your edit! :) Maybe I should accept the answer but I'll wait for some more upvotes before accepting my own answer...

Comment: it was the easiest way i could find... but then your Q and A have the exact same time, so looks like you just asked to write the answer ;)

Comment: @emostar Oh, yes!, definitely!, now I remember, I tried that "share your knowledge Q&A style" thing! I'd totally forgotten!

Comment: This only works for your contrived entry list. If you had two people tied at first place for example, the ZREVRANK call would not return the value you wanted.