# Implementing Dense Rank with Redis Sorted Sets

Tags: redis, ranking, sortedset

I'm trying to implement a leaderboard with rankings, the data being stored as sorted sets in Redis. The part I'm trying to figure out is how to implement Dense (i.e. "[1-2-2-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Dense_ranking_.28.221223.22_ranking.29)") ranking, where, for example, users are ranked thusly:

```
Score   User    Rank
---------------------
22      user1   1
21      user2   2
21      user3   2
21      user4   2
20      user5   3
20      user6   3
```

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14944280/2177 is almost what I need, but it amounts to "[1-2-2-4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Standard_competition_ranking_.28.221224.22_ranking.29)" ranking, which is not desirable for my application, e.g.:

```
1-2-2-4 Ranking 
Score   User    Rank
---------------------
22     user1    1
21     user2    2
21     user3    2
21     user4    2
20     user5    5
20     user6    5
```

This seems like it would be a fairly common use case. Has anyone successfully implemented such a thing in Redis, and if so, how?

Comment: There are libraries available for this now, Kudos to the developers!
https://github.com/agoragames/leaderboard-python https://github.com/agoragames/leaderboard-python#ports Thank the reviewers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding a second sorted set that contains only the unique scores, which I can then query for their respective positions in the dense ranking.

Comment: How did you implement this ?
Unique Score set would have values [22, 21, 20] which means rank of  unique score 20 is 3, but you would need it to be 5. I'm confused. am I missing something here ?

Comment: @RegMem I think you meant `CompetitionRanking` as opposed to `DenseRanking`